# Getting wrong timezone time from the TIMESTAMP in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, timezone, typeorm

In my application, I am using `MySQL(version: 5.6.10)` and storing the time as `TIMESTAMP`. When I try to retrieve the time, I am getting the wrong time.

My Timezone is `+5:30`. When I store timestamp, it is storing with `+00:00` timezone. When I retrieve the time, the time is coming by subtracting ie. `-05:30` instead of `+05:30`.

Let me add an example

If I store a time using `NOW()` at `2020-11-02 12:00:00`, it is stored as `2020-11-02 06:30:00`. But, when I retrieve the data, it is coming as `2020-11-02 01:00:00` again by subtracting `-05:30`. I don't understand why this is happening.

Please help me solve this.

Thank you...

Comment: *My Timezone is +5:30.* Does this is timezone of your client host, server host, both? Does your server is thinking the same? *If I store a time using NOW() at 2020-11-02 12:00:00* Where is this "at 2020-11-02 12:00:00"? at your client? at the server? does you use `INSERT NOW() ... INTO ...`? *it is stored as 2020-11-02 06:30:00* How do you detect this?

Comment: @Akina, `My Timezone is +5:30` is my timezone where my client web application is running. When I run `INSERT NOW() ... INTO ...`, it is stored as `2020-11-02 06:30:00`. I saw this value in the MySQL workbench. When I retrieve this, I am getting as `2020-11-02 01:00:00`. Please help me understand this

Comment: Hi.  There's a lot missing here.  Please edit your question to include the code that retrieves the timestamp from the server and sends it to the client.  Please also include the code on the client side that displays the timestamp into the form you're reading it.  Please also tell us the exact time zone settings in your MYSQL server (`SELECT @@GLOBAL.time_zone, @@SESSION.time_zone;`).  Please also tell us the time zone setting on your server and client  (`Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`).

Comment: You might also want to read [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the Stack Overflow help center.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change timezone in php.ini file else set timezone in default-time-zone='+00:00'
my.cnf, If you don't want to changeanything at server end then run query

SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`column_name`) FROM `tablename`